# SQL query to fetch all results in one query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

**Test data:**

```
    id  date       company  location  
   ----------------------------------
    1   03/01/2016  ABC      india     
    2   03/25/2016  ABC      us
    3   02/24/2016  ABC      india
    4   02/25/2016  ABC      us
    5   03/02/2016  ABC      india
```

Query #1

```
select count(id) 
from table 
where company = 'ABC' 
  and date between 03/01/2016 and 03/31/2016
```

Query #2

```
select count(id) 
from table 
where company = 'ABC' 
  and date between 02/01/2016 and 02/29/2016
```

Need to calculate location wise count for current and previous months.
How to write a SQL query to return location wise like the below in one query?

**Expected result:**

```
   company currentmonth   Previousmonth   location
    ABC      2                   1          india
    ABC      1                   1           us
```

Comment: it doesn't help ,could you provide test data  in form of temp table which is in line with your expected data ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try some thing like subtract current date yearmm format (ex: 201603) and  yearmm format of date from table (ex:201603) if it result to 0 treat as current month, else previous month, hope it will help:

```
SELECT company,
       location,
       sum(iif(d = 0, 0, 1)) cm,
       sum(iif(d = 0, 1, 0)) pm        
FROM (SELECT company, 
       location, 
       CONVERT(INT,
         CONVERT(CHAR(4), GetDate(), 120) + 
         CONVERT(CHAR(2), GetDate(), 101)
       ) -
       CONVERT(INT, 
         CONVERT(CHAR(4), date, 120) + 
         CONVERT(CHAR(2), date, 101)
       )  as d
FROM table) vw
GROUP BY company, location
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
select company,
       sum(case when month(date)=month(getdate()) 
                        then 1 else 0 end) as currentMonth,
       sum(case when month(date)=month(dateadd(MONTH,-1,getdate())) 
                        then 1 else 0 end) as Previuosmonth,
       location 
  from yourTable
 where month(date) between month(dateadd(MONTH,-1,getdate())) and month(getdate())
   AND company='ABC'
 group by company, location
```

Since you made two queries and filter both with current month (march) and previous. I decided to use the function `MONTH` to extract the month from the current date (`getdate()`) of the system and subtract 1 that way you will always have the current month and the previous one.

**EDIT**

As pointed out by @DhananjayaKuppu I fixed the problem for when you have a month as January, since the `month` function returns an integer it would return 0 in my calculation. Now it is fixed.

Comment: Thanks,Can you please tell me how to display currentmonth and previuos month difference in percentage as new column by location wise?

Comment: Percentage based on the total? from both months? what would be the result?

Comment: Jorge, just a question would previous month logic works in cases where current month is January and month in date is December.  To my knowledge month(date) will be 12 and (month(getDate()) -1) will return 0 and it might not add to previous month sum. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @DhananjayaKuppu Hmmm you make a really good question. In fact it wouldn't I will edit my answer. thank you.